# klist not updating group membership

Tags: windows-10, membership, klist

A have a network folder with a group permissions.
When I update the group with new permissions, I can't get the users computer to update group membership without a logoff

I'm trying to update group membership with command klist but it does not work

I have tried both command `Klist purge` and `klist -lh 0 -li 0x3e4 purge` and after gpupdate /force

Sometimes is says success, but it does not work or It says that it need to logoff anyway

We are running windows 10

Does anyone know what could be wrong. Any ideas?